# RadioButton in ListView

Tags: android

I want to create a ListView with a RadioButton in every row.
I'm using a CursorAdapter and I'm binding it in the right way, but I cannot manage correctly the RadioButton.
I want that at any moment only one RadioButton to be checked (so when I check one, I would like the one that was checked before to uncheck).
Furthermore, when I put the RadioButton on the row, I cannot manage anymore the setOnItemClickListener.
Do you know any tutorial that will work for me? Or can you give me any info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the previous ans I was sleepy I guess. Try the following

```
setListAdapter(new ResourceCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, cursor));

listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: you could handle the logic yourself by putting an extra column in your table, not sure if that would be too expensive though.